# Notification for android giving error for Notification class

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications, stackmob

I am creating a small app for android for notification.

But it gives an Error in Notification class error (API level supported for 11 or 16).
Then I tried using NotificationCompat class but it shows resources can not be resolved to a type while I `import package import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;`

In other words, if I use Notification class then it give API level Error, and if I use NotificationCompat then it gives that resource error. How can I resolve both these errors?

```
 public void createNotification(View view) {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    // Context context=new Context();
    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
     NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "star.ankit90@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: I took this code from this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html ..

Comment: please tell me solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've had compilation errors using your code.

This fixed code compiles successfully:

```
// Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentTitle("New mail from " + "star.ankit90@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Hide the notification after its selected
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Maybe it will work for you. if not a stack trace can help.

Comment: I used this code but still that error is not removing (NotificationCompat can not be reolved )

Comment: Are you sure you added the compatibility lib?
(right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Add support library)

Comment: give me exact solution for this.

Comment: ctrl+shift+o might help you, just delete the notification import before.